# php preg_match_all with regex, string parse. multiple rows

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, match

I'm newbie php programmer.

i serious problem T_T....

use php preg_match_all with regex,

> $pattern = "/<<>>(.*){0,20}?(<<>>)/";
>   $text = <<>>id1<<>>2<<>>3<<>>4<<>>5<<>>6<<>>7<<>>8<>>9<<>>10<<>>11<<>>12<<>>13<<>>14<<>>15<<>>16<<>>17<<>>18<<>>19<<>>20<<>>21<<>>";
>               $text.= "<<>>id2<<>>2<<>>3<<>>4<<>>5<<>>6<<>>7<<>>8<>>9<<>>10<<>>11<<>>12<<>>13<<>>14<<>>15<<>>16<<>>17<<>>18<<>>19<<>>20<<>>21<<>>";
>               $text.= "<<>>id3<<>>2<<>>3<<>>4<<>>5<<>>6<<>>7<<>>8<>>9<<>>10<<>>11<<>>12<<>>13<<>>14<<>>15<<>>16<<>>17<<>>18<<>>19<<>>20<<>>21<<>>";
>
> preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $match);

this result.

> Array (
> [0] => Array ([0] => <<>>id1<<>>2<<>>3<<>>4<<>>5<<>>6<<>>7<<>>8<>>9<<>>10<<>>11<<>>12<<>>13<<>>14<<>>15<<>>16<<>>17<<>>18<<>>19<<>>20<<>>21<<>><<>>id2<<>>2<<>>3<<>>4<<>>5<<>>6<<>>7<<>>8<>>9<<>>10<<>>11<<>>12<<>>13<<>>14<<>>15<<>>16<<>>17<<>>18<<>>19<<>>20<<>>21<<>><<>>id3<<>>2<<>>3<<>>4<<>>5<<>>6<<>>7<<>>8<>>9<<>>10<<>>11<<>>12<<>>13<<>>14<<>>15<<>>16<<>>17<<>>18<<>>19<<>>20<<>>21<<>>
>           )
>   [1] => Array
>           (
>               [0] => id1<<>>2<<>>3<<>>4<<>>5<<>>6<<>>7<<>>8<>>9<<>>10<<>>11<<>>12<<>>13<<>>14<<>>15<<>>16<<>>17<<>>18<<>>19<<>>20<<>>21<<>><<>>id2<<>>2<<>>3<<>>4<<>>5<<>>6<<>>7<<>>8<>>9<<>>10<<>>11<<>>12<<>>13<<>>14<<>>15<<>>16<<>>17<<>>18<<>>19<<>>20<<>>21<<>><<>>id3<<>>2<<>>3<<>>4<<>>5<<>>6<<>>7<<>>8<>>9<<>>10<<>>11<<>>12<<>>13<<>>14<<>>15<<>>16<<>>17<<>>18<<>>19<<>>20<<>>21
>           )
>       [2] => Array
>           (
>               [0] => <<>>
>           )
>   )

however, i want result, below.

> [0] => (
>
> > [0] => id1
> >     [1] => 1
> >     [2] => 2
> >     ...
> >     )
>
> [1] => (
>
> > [0] => id2
> >     [1] => 1
> >     [2] => 2
> >     ...
> >     )

how do regex pattern, this result?

Edit1.

array_filter(preg_split('/>/', $text));

> Array
>   (
>       [1] => id1
>       [2] => 2
>       [3] => 3
>       [4] => 4
>       [5] => 5
>       [6] => 6
>       [7] => 7
>       [8] => 8
>       [9] => 9
>       [10] => 10
>       [11] => 11
>       [12] => 12
>       [13] => 13
>       [14] => 14
>       [15] => 15
>       [16] => 16
>       [17] => 17
>       [18] => 18
>       [19] => 19
>       [20] => 20
>       [21] => 21
>       [23] => id2
>       [24] => 2
>       [25] => 3
>       [26] => 4
>       [27] => 5
>       [28] => 6
>       [29] => 7
>       [30] => 8
>       [31] => 9
>       [32] => 10
>       [33] => 11
>       [34] => 12
>       [35] => 13
>       [36] => 14
>       [37] => 15
>       [38] => 16
>       [39] => 17
>       [40] => 18
>       [41] => 19
>       [42] => 20
>       [43] => 21
>       [45] => id3
>       [46] => 2
>       [47] => 3
>       [48] => 4
>       [49] => 5
>       [50] => 6
>       [51] => 7
>       [52] => 8
>       [53] => 9
>       [54] => 10
>       [55] => 11
>       [56] => 12
>       [57] => 13
>       [58] => 14
>       [59] => 15
>       [60] => 16
>       [61] => 17
>       [62] => 18
>       [63] => 19
>       [64] => 20
>       [65] => 21
>   )

but, i want

> [0] => ([0] =>id1 [1]=> 1 ...)
>   [1] => ([0] =>id2 [1]=> 1 ...)
>   [2] => ([0] =>id3 [1]=> 1 ...)

how do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Alternative approach: exploding your string

Instead of using regex (which is slow), try splitting your line using [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.explode.php) function.

```
explode('<<>>', $text);
```

This will create empty elements at the beginning and at the end of the array. To get rid of them, you can use `array_filter`:

```
array_filter(explode('<<>>', $text));
```

I noticed, however, that between 8 and 9 you have `<>>` (note missing `<`). If this is desired and you need to deal with that kind of input too, you can use `preg_split`, which will allow you to do the same thing as `explode`, but with "multiple" delimiters:

```
array_filter(preg_split('/<?<>>/', $text));
```

### Original approach: `preg_match_all`

If you, however, insist on using `preg_match_all`, then you need to be aware of a few things:

1. `{0,20}` makes `*` unnecessary. I.e. what you're looking after is `.{0,20}`, not `.*{0,20}`. Otherwise it makes no sense.
2. You can prevent `<<>>` from appearing in the result by surrounding them with non-capturing group like this: `(?:<<>>)`.
3. To take care of [excessive greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), you can use `?` operator after operators like `{x,y}`, `*` and `+`. This will make matching lazy.

Having this in mind, we can construct the following regex:

```
preg_match_all('/(.{0,20}?)(?:<?<>>)/', $text, $matches);
```

This will create one empty element at the beginning of the array. I leave it up to you to get rid of it.

---

As you see, using `preg_match_all` is a lot more complicated than using `explode()` or `preg_split`. That's why I recommend you to use the first approach.